# Android design. Images too large

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello have to make a header in my application but the images i have received are too big for a mobile phone. Applying `wrap_content` on both height and width is giving a very odd look. and specifying the `layout_height` and `layout_width` is scaling it really wrong!

I have to now specify the designer how it should look like. I have no idea what to tell him and how to specify. Can anyone here help me please?

I am giving an example image. The idea is that i want it to look right on the screen. [image]

This is obviously a very large image. And results are even more shocking. Can anyone please help in this matter?

Comment: for quick fix put this image in drawable-hdpi. Now check how it looks .

Comment: Sorry to be that guy, but you spelled 'Previous' wrong.

Comment: @JohnLeehey It's the designer. You see what I have to deal with?

Comment: Why don't you give your designer specifications as to what size you need it? Basically how large it should be on the screen given the density. Make some views at various px sizes and see which looks good to you.

Comment: that's what i am asking. I don't know what to specify!

Comment: You specify what size you want it to be...whether that be in physical dimensions (millimeters, inches) or pixels. Alex's answer below has some good info, but in the end, the size that you want your graphics to be is up to you. You'll always want to start with the largest size you'll need and scale down from there, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html . I also suggest reading this simple article http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/

Some simples rules are:

- You may need different images for different screen densities.
- You may need different layouts for different screen sizes.
- I usually start considering a "normal size" and "medium density" device, which means a resolution of 320 x 480 pixels and a density of 160 dpi.

So, to put it simple, if you ask him to make a 160 x 240 size image, it will have half the width of the screen and half the height, in a medium density device. If you install the same app in a small density device, the image will look bigger (compared to the size of the screen). And if you install in a high density device, the image will look smaller.

Then you may ask him to make other images with different size to fit well in the devices with other densities. Always consider the ratio 75 : 100 : 150. Which means that if the image has 100 x 100 pixels in the medium density, it should have 75 x 75 in the small density and 150 x 150 in the high density.

Answer (score 0):

this is the most up-to-date instructions of google for the designers of android apps:
http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

other useful links for designers:

what's new on android 4 (newest version of android , aka ICS - ice scream sandwich) :
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html
http://www.android.com/about/ice-cream-sandwich/
video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-AZ08wCwJA

what's new on android 3  (tablets version of android , aka honeycomb , but most things are relavant for 4.0 too) :
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html
videos:
http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/honeycomb-highlights.html
http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/designing-and-implementing-android-uis-for-phones-and-tablets.html

some information of the different screens handling on android :
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link: http://resizepic.com/

Resize you image online into these sizes and paste them in these folders correspondingly:

1. 72 X 72 - Drawable-hdpi
2. 48 X 48 - Drawable-mdpi
3. 36 X 36 - Drawable-ldpi
4. 96 X 96 - Drawable-xhdpi

This is the best easy way of solving it.